# TFS RM: How to turn off debug info

Tags: tfs-2015, ms-release-management

I'm using the Powershell on Target Machines task in a release definition.

This task is producing by default a lot of debug info in the logs:

> 2016-04-19T09:29:13.9259230Z Executing the powershell script:
> C:\Temp\agent2\tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines\1.0.2\PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1
>
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]Entering script
> PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z
>
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]protocol =
> Http
>
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]resourceFilteringMethod =
> machineNames
>
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]scriptPath = C:\RM\foobar\2013.10.16110.02-01\foobar.ps1
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]scriptArguments =
> -foobar DEV -foobar "foobar"
>
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0821546Z ##[debug]runPowershellInParallel = true
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]testCertificate =
> true
>
> =2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]initializationScriptPath =
> 2016-04-19T09:29:14.0665281Z ##[debug]machineNames

and so on.

How can I turn this debug info off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such setting to turn off the debug info by default.

But you can modify the .ps1 files in PowerShellOnTargetMachines task by removing -`Verbose` flags, then you won't see the debug info.

[image]

Comment: You mean to modify the .ps1 files from the build agent?